# using singleton in kotlin and starting a service

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was trying to make my `Service` (foreground service) class a singleton like so:

```
object MyClass: Service() {
}
```

when I do this, I can't send an intent to start the service like this:

```
  val mIntent = Intent(this, MyClass::class.java)
  mIntent.action = MyClass.ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
  ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, mIntent)
```

I get an IllegalAccessException, like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void com.it.gy.MyClass.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>
```

this exception is supposed to be caused when class at hand is not public, but, `object MyClass` is supposed to be so by default. I could make the class a public and make a private constructor to implement a custom singleton, but, I'd like to use the Kotlin syntax as far as possible. How may I do that?

Comment: Service is an android component, you cannot make it an object because it has to be created (and destroyed) by the system. Closes you can get to making it a singleton is hold hard static reference thats set/unset in services oncreate/ondestroy.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not supported by the operating system. A `Service` needs to be a `class`, as Android will want to create an instance of that class.

Comment: so making it a singleton is a bad idea/design pattern? Since the app at hand requires only 1 service, I thought it was appropriate

Comment: @juztcode: A `Service` is a natural singleton. What is a bad idea is trying to use `object` syntax from Kotlin for that singleton. Personally, I try to have as little business logic in the `Service` as possible, moving that logic out into other classes (e.g., repositories). So, to me, trying to call functions on the `Service` from outside is a bad design pattern. You are still welcome to implement that, but you will need to [use Pawel's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75276264/using-singleton-in-kotlin-and-starting-a-service/75276297?noredirect=1#comment132831259_75276264).

Comment: by a `natural singleton` do you mean that an Intent sent to start the service does not spawn it multiple times even if multiple Intents are sent? The doc doesn't seem to quite clearly mention that somehow I think: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services , I wonder if I've missed it though

Comment: @juztcode: "do you mean that an Intent sent to start the service does not spawn it multiple times even if multiple Intents are sent?" -- the first `startService()` call creates the service. If the service has not yet been destroyed, subsequent `startService()` calls will only trigger `onStartCommand()` of the existing service instance and will not create a new instance.